# Context on simple query

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm making a simple database query on MongoDB, and I see 2 different ways to call Context.

First way with timeout:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
defer cancel()
result := collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": userID})
```

Second way, calling directly with context.Background()

```
result := collection.FindOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"_id": userID})
```

If I use the second way and there is a long delay, would it wait forever or timeout at one point?
I find the second solution more elegant with less lines of code, but as I'm new in Go I may misunderstand the risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set socket timeout & connect timeout via [URI options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), the second option should time out when these timeouts are exceeded.

Comment: So on my rest API I set a `&http.Server{WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second}` so that means after 10 seconds it will timeout?

Comment: No, your server's timeout has no relation to the timeout used by MongoDB client.

Comment: OK, so in my case the MongoDB never times out, so I better always use context with timeout. Thanks